On every run jar file using hadoop it is always stuck
On every run jar file using hadoop it is always stuck here in the last line.
Here, try the Foil Jar located in the hadoop file itself, but with the same result, it gets stuck in the last line, although at http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps/ACCEPTED it shows that the operation has been accepted.
>hadoop jar C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar wordcount /Dir/Input.txt /output/wordcount_output 2024-06-15 05:17:17,931 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032 2024-06-15 05:17:19,324 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/XPRISTO/.staging/job_1718416283436_0006 2024-06-15 05:17:19,914 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1 2024-06-15 05:17:20,133 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1 2024-06-15 05:17:20,379 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1718416283436_0006 2024-06-15 05:17:20,379 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: [] 2024-06-15 05:17:20,619 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found 2024-06-15 05:17:20,620 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'. 2024-06-15 05:17:20,687 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1718416283436_0006 2024-06-15 05:17:20,734 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-EEB2KG7:8088/proxy/application_1718416283436_0006/ 2024-06-15 05:17:20,736 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1718416283436_0006 // <--- here stuck

I think the problem is in the jar file, but when running more than one file, it turns out that the problem is somewhere else.
To be honest, I don't know exactly where the problem lies. I checked all the Hadoop files, but nothing was found. if there any file related to this problem help me to know it.
yarn-site.xml
<configuration>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.shuffleHandler</value>
</property>

</configuration>


The url to track the job: http://DESKTOP-EEB2KG7:8088/proxy/application_1718416283436_0006/ what does that say?

Accepted isn't the same as running. It could mean a nodemanager isn't running, but the ResourceManager is waiting for that
